# removing current time while converting date using Date function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need all Saturday and sunday of current year

there for i am using this function

```
   var x = new Date();
        //set the financial year starting date
        var currentyear = x.getFullYear();
        var nextyear = x.getFullYear() + 1;
        x.setFullYear(currentyear, 00, 00);
        //set the next financial year starting date
        var y = new Date();
        y.setFullYear(currentyear, 12, 31);
        var j = 1;
        var count = 0;
        //getting the all mondays in a financial year
        for (var i = 0; x < y; i += j) {
            if (x.getDay() === 0) {
                //console.log("Date : " + x.getDate() + "/" +
                //  (x.getMonth() + 1) + "<br>");
                x = new Date(x.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                // x = new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate());
                holidaylist.push(x);
                j = 7;
                count++;

            } else {
                j = 1;
                x = new Date(x.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            }

        }
```

and its giveing me perfect saturday and sunday but the problem is

i dont want any time behind my date

**from**

```
Sat Mar 03 1973 15:16:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

i want something like this

**to**

```
Sat Mar 03 1973 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

how can i get 00 time from this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setHours](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp) property of javascript to set the time of the date object
Try using

```
(new Date()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

```js
function myFunction() {
     var d = new Date();
     d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the date after setting the time.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try toDateString();

```js
let z = new Date();
console.log(z);

console.log(new Date(z.toDateString()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log(d);
console.log(new Date(d.setHours(0,0,0,0)));
```